# What is the usage of slash in table data html tag?

Tags: html, html-table

I searched on the web but have not found anything similar to this

```
<td><input name=\"mname\" type=\"text\" id=\"mname\" readonly=\"true\" style=\"background-color:#000; color:#FFF\" value='$mname'/></td>
```

It is a bit confusing why we have `name=\"mname\"` and what is the difference if we say `name="mname"`

Comment: Are you happening to be looking at PHP code by any chance?

Comment: Yes. `value='$mname'` indicates that.

Comment: \ simply skips one character that is " to build correct html doc.You can also use single quote **<option value='"asd'>test</option>** to use " without \ character

Comment: @BoltClock Yes I'm using php as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is echoed from PHP.

Guess, this is a part of a PHP block which is similar to the following

```
<?php
    $mname = "Some Value";
    echo "<td><input name=\"mname\" type=\"text\" id=\"mname\" readonly=\"true\" style=\"background-color:#000; color:#FFF\" value='$mname'/></td>";
?>
```

The given string is perfectly valid if it is echoed from a PHP block with some value in $mname variable.

The slash is to escape double quotes in a string which is surrounded by double quotes.